# Preferred language and device language don't match

Tags: ios, swift

Say I launch my iOS app with these settings:

```
Preferred Language: "ja"
Language Code: "ja"
Region Code: "US"
```

Then, I close the app and change the `Preferred Language` to `"de"`.
Now the settings look like this:

```
Preferred Language: "de"
Language Code: "ja"
Region Code: "US"
```

This creates a problem, because text will be translated to german but the built in device formatting for dates and times will be formatted as japanese.

How can you change the `Language Code`? Ideally, when a user's preferred language changes, the language code should also change correct? What's the best approach to handle this?

Comment: Across Apple's platforms, the date/time/currency formats are distinct from the language, e.g., a user may wish to use US English as their language but with metric units and 24 hour clock. So the premise that these should match the language is flawed…

Comment: Basically you shouldn't try to "fix" this on the app side, but rather use the locale's formatting for things displayed to the user, and trust that they have set it up the way they prefer. Or if your question is how to configure this as a user (rather than how to handle it as a developer), then it should probably be asked on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Then why when I change the preferred language to Japanese does it change the language/region code to ja_US? Shouldn’t it remain as en_US?

Comment: Region and language are different settings. I agree that as a user the configuration may sometimes produce unexpected results, but regardless of that you shouldn't try to circumvent properties of the OS-level configuration inside your app as an app developer. (Or, if you think something locale-related is so key to your app that the user may wish to have a distinct setting from other apps, offer an optional override, e.g., in a weather app you could allow changing between Celsius and Fahrenheit independently of the locale.)

Comment: Right, I'm not suggesting circumventing the OS. I do think adjusting the settings from a user perspective should be clearer though. Thanks for your insights.